# Merge nodes with apoc and average property values

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

When merging nodes with:

```
apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes, {properties:'combine', mergeRels:true})
```

The nodes' relationships will be merged as well, and their properties will be concatenated in a list:

```
(merged_nodes)-[merged_edges]-()

merged_edges.weight = [2,4,6]
```

Instead of a list I want an average

```
merged_edges.weight = avg([2,4,6]) = 4
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the average after you've done the merge, there's an APOC function to get the average of a list of values:

```
...
MATCH (merged_nodes)-[merged_edges]-()
SET merged_edges.weight = apoc.coll.avg(merged_edges.weight)
```